Access Token not returned by /token Azure B2C
I've started attempting to create a SPA with Web API connectivity through Azure AD B2C. I've successfully done this in the normal Microsoft Entra Id. I am following this guide.
Here are details regarding my setup.
Here's my WebAPI (2f135ed1-fd85-4ea3-956a-0e5ee71a2957):

Here's my front-end (336e86e4-7b42-462f-b068-af0edd0ba226):

I have received the React SPA and Web API code form this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-react-spa-app#step-3-get-the-react-sample-code
It instructs me to configure my authConfig.js in order to setup the app correctly.
Here's my SPA auth.config:
`
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */

import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

/**
 * Enter here the user flows and custom policies for your B2C application
 * To learn more about user flows, visit: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-   directory-b2c/user-flow-overview
 * To learn more about custom policies, visit: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview
 */
export const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: 'B2C_1_signupsignin1',
        forgotPassword: 'B2C_1_reset_password1',
        editProfile: 'B2C_1_edit_profile1',
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: "https://shawnpeeryb2c.b2clogin.com/shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1"
        },

        forgotPassword: {
            authority: 'https://shawnpeeryb2c.b2clogin.com/shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_reset_password1',
        },
        editProfile: {
            authority: 'https://shawnpeeryb2c.b2clogin.com/shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_edit_profile1',
        },
    },
    authorityDomain: 'shawnpeeryb2c.b2clogin.com',
};


/**
 * Configuration object to be passed to MSAL instance on creation. 
 * For a full list of MSAL.js configuration parameters, visit:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md 
 */
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '336e86e4-7b42-462f-b068-af0edd0ba226', // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority, // Choose SUSI as your default authority.
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain], // Mark your B2C tenant's domain as trusted.
        redirectUri: '/', // You must register this URI on Azure Portal/App Registration. Defaults to window.location.origin
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false, // If "true", will navigate back to the original request location before processing the auth code response.
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

/**
 * Add here the endpoints and scopes when obtaining an access token for protected web APIs. For more information, see:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md
 */
export const protectedResources = {
    apiTodoList: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:5000/api/todolist',
        scopes: {
            read: ['https://shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservices-api/Todos.Read'],
            write: ['https://shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservices-api/Todos.Write'],
        },
    },
};

/**
 * Scopes you add here will be prompted for user consent during sign-in.
 * By default, MSAL.js will add OIDC scopes (openid, profile, email) to any login request.
 * For more information about OIDC scopes, visit: 
 * https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes
 */
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [...protectedResources.apiTodoList.scopes.read, ...protectedResources.apiTodoList.scopes.write],
};

`

Here's my Web API authConfig.js
`
const passportConfig = {
    credentials: {
        tenantName: 'shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientID: '2f135ed1-fd85-4ea3-956a-0e5ee71a2957',
    },
    policies: {
        policyName: 'B2C_1_signupsignin1',
    },
    metadata: {
        b2cDomain: 'shawnpeeryb2c.b2clogin.com',
        authority: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
        discovery: '.well-known/openid-configuration',
        version: 'v2.0',
    },
    settings: {
        isB2C: true,
        validateIssuer: false,
        passReqToCallback: true,
        loggingLevel: 'info',
        loggingNoPII: false,
    },
    protectedRoutes: {
        todolist: {
            endpoint: '/api/todolist',
            delegatedPermissions: {
                read: ['Todos.Read'],
                write: ['Todos.Write'],
            },
        },
    },
};

module.exports = passportConfig;
`

When I run the apps, I can login just fine through azure. However,when I look at the token requests, it doesn't show me an access token. Just id tokens.
And I have the following set for both app registrations:

But even still it doesn't give me an access token.
This is in my app's request:

This is what azure sends back:

Here are repos to my current code:
React SPA: https://github.com/shawn-peery/B2C-Demo-SPA
Web API: https://github.com/shawn-peery/B2C-Demo-WebAPI
I appreciate any help!
Edit: Added github links.
Edit: Grammer

Can you share your GitHub repo here, I don't find any code from the GitHub repo you shared in the question.

@DasariKamali Sure one sec. I'll make one real quick.

@DasariKamali I have added the github repos for reference. I basically grabbed a demo project provided by the documentation.

It looks like you have a dash that shouldn't be there in the scopes. ".../microservices-api/..." but the App Registration screenshot where you create the scopes shows "microservicesapi"

Are the last screenshots from Postman

@Rukmini Naw they're from my FireFox Browser.

And @jefftrotman Thanks for the information. I ended up cancelling the Azure B2C I had going on. If I come back I will test it again and verify it's correct. I thought I copied and pasted most things but thanks for the input! I'll try again in the future


Note that: Fetching access token in Azure AD B2C mainly depends on scope you are passing in the request.

Created a Backend application, exposed an API and added scope same as you like below:

Added API permissions in Frontend application:

I agree with @jefftrotman, you are passing scope as .../microservices-api/... where as your application scope do not contain - that is microservicesapi.
Initially when I passed scope as https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservices-api/Todos.Read https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservices-api/Todos.Write offline_access openid as you I dint not receive access token in response:
Grant type: Authorization code (With PKCE)

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Client ID : ClientID
Code Challenge Method : SHA-256
Scope: https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservices-api/Todos.Read https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservices-api/Todos.Write offline_access openid



Only ID token and refresh token generated:

Hence to resolve the error pass scope as https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservicesapi/Todos.Read https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservicesapi/Todos.Write offline_access openid
Now access token too got generated:

In your case pass scope as:
scopes: {
            read: ['https://shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservicesapi/Todos.Read'],
            write: ['https://shawnpeeryb2c.onmicrosoft.com/microservicesapi/Todos.Write'],
        }


